# jQuery: Infinite loop that doesn't crash the browser

Tags: jquery, loops, infinite-loop

I was wondering if it was possible to create an infinite loop which does not crash the browser I am working on a gallery type thing which will pulse as it scrolls across the screen.

This is what I have so far (which obviously crashes the browser):

```
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 1){
        $('.block').each(function(index) {  
            $(this).css('left', $(this).position().left - 10)
            if (($(this).position().left) < ($(window).width() * 0.4)) {
              $(this).html('<p>Test 1</p>');
              $(this).animate({
              width: "500px",
              height: "500px",
              }, 500 );
            }else if (($(this).position().left) < ($(window).width() * 0.2)) {
              $(this).html('<p>Test 1</p>');
              $(this).animate({
              width: "600px",
              height: "600px",
              }, 500 );
            }
        });
    }
```

Any tips would be grand!

Comment: Well, usually `window.setInterval` (or, even better, `window.setTimeout`) are used to create this effect (of infinite loop).

Comment: Oh i totally forgot about those functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use [window.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) like code bellow (it will be execute with interval 3 second):

```
function LoopForever() {
    $('.block').each(function(index) {  
       $(this).css('left', $(this).position().left - 10)
       if (($(this).position().left) < ($(window).width() * 0.4)) {
           $(this).html('<p>Test 1</p>');
           $(this).animate({
              width: "500px",
          height: "500px",
           }, 500 );
       }else if (($(this).position().left) < ($(window).width() * 0.2)) {
           $(this).html('<p>Test 1</p>');
           $(this).animate({
          width: "600px",
          height: "600px",
           }, 500 );
       }
    });
}

var interval = self.setInterval(function(){LoopForever()},3000);

//call code bllow to stop interval
//window.clearInterval(interval);
```

Note: 1000 = 1 second;

Answer (score 2):

For better performance, use requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animations can be chained, so to run one animation then run another, you can call animate twice. It is also possible to add non-animations into the queue using [.queue(callback(next))](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2).

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLEgR/)

```
<div class="hello">Hi</div>​

.hello {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}​

$(".hello")
    .animate({ left: 200 })
    .animate({ width: 200, height: 200 })​
```

Bonus tip: if you want an infinite loop, just pass true into while: `while (true) { ... }`.

Comment: While that is cool to know, I want them to move across the screen and grow/shrink while moving but only if they reach a certain point in the viewport.

Comment: One way to do that would be to calculate when to change from the moving animation to the moving-and-scaling animation. Alternatively, you could use the `step` callback option to animate to start the scaling animation once the condition is met, and use the `queue: false` option to make it happen at the same time as the first animation.