# Display html result at each round of javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, fadein

This has got to be answered already, but I can't find it.
[EDIT: very similar solution here:
 [Fade in each li one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109870/fade-in-each-li-one-by-one), however do have a look at WaldemarIce's solution below which also takes care of infinite looping very nicely]
I want consecutive rows of a table to be shown with fade in and fade out, one at a time, while all the other rows are hidden. I am using jQuery, see code below. 
What I want to happen is for each row to fade in and out, one after the other. 
What happens is that all the rows fade in and out together, simultaneously. How do I separate the events?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    var eqvar = "tr:eq(" + i + ")";
    var thisrow = $("table#hidden").find(eqvar);
    $(thisrow).fadeIn(2000);
    $(thisrow).fadeOut(2000);
  }
});
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<table id="hidden"><tbody>
<tr class="hide"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
<tr class="hide"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fade in each li one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109870/fade-in-each-li-one-by-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of code showing each row of the table, one at time, in infinite loop:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function present () {
    $('#hidden tr')
      .each(function (idx) {
        $(this).delay(idx * 1300).fadeIn(250).delay(800).fadeOut(250)
      })
      .promise().then(present)
  }

  present()
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hide"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="hide"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="hide"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly. I was mucking about with `setTimeout()` which obviously isn't delaying execution of the next step. 
So, the magic wand here is the `delay()` method. Thanks for pointing to that.
–Of course much more elegant with `.each(function(){});` I started with that but then I thought that might have been the source of the problem... 
:(

Comment: @danbae glad to help :)

Comment: Now even simplier, based on @VMT answer.

Comment: Next problem: to find a way that makes this start over again when it has reached the bottom row of the table. I looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020630/jquery-infinite-loop-that-doesnt-crash-the-browser) but it didn't work for me. Could you maybe help me again? This was really tricky.

Comment: @danbae Try example in my answer. Is it working? I cant test it, I am writing on cellphone.

Comment: Works like a charm, but I will have to read up on the stuff you are using. Where is "idx" given a value?
`.promise().then(_=> present())` reads like modern poetry to me :)
Thanks a lot, anyway!

Comment: @danbae It is hard to explain in few word... PS: I improved it, now it is simplier.

Comment: @ WaldemarIce could you maybe edit your original post text ("Is this what you want?") to describe that the code now also includes looping the entire list indefinitely? It would help future visitors to understand what they are looking at.

Comment: @danbae Done. And slightly improved.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table#hidden tr").each(function(i,v){
        setTimeout(function(){
      var thisrow = $(v);
      $(thisrow).fadeIn(2000);
      $(thisrow).fadeOut(2000);
    }, 4000 * i); 
  });
});
```